# CSS styling vertical-align is not working

Tags: html, css

Please have a look. Here is the [**plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/IXTXuQJmMBWwvCJ27HRm?p=preview) demo

For the 1st  div
I want to center the text "A" and "web designer and developer".
"A" must have the height of other parts. 
For the 2nd  div
The text "Photographer" must vertically align.

What is the problem here?

```
.intro .text h4,
.intro .text h5 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  border-top: 2px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}
.intro .text h4 {
  float: left;
}
.intro .text h5 {
  float: left;
}
.intro .text h4 span {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 77px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.intro .text h5 span {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: so A and web.. will be in one row in center?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use vertical align on elements that are floated.

Here I removed the floats, added a -4px margin to the right (to remove the natural spacing after an inline element to keep the borders together) and added some padding. You can use this technique for the second part you want aligned.

```
.intro .text h4, .intro .text h5{
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  border-top: 2px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.intro .text h4{
  margin-right: -4px;
}

.intro .text h5{
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPpJma